# pandas: concatenate two DataFrames with sorted MultiIndexes such that result has a sorted MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, multi-index

Please, let me know how to concatenate two DataFrames with sorted MultiIndexes such that result has a sorted MultiIndex.

Since, both are sorted, **the algorithm has to have linear complexity in terms of the total number of rows in both DataFrames** (this is the complexity of merging 2 sorted lists, which is effectively what the problem is here).

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
t1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'i1':[0,0,1,1,2,2],
                        'i2':[0,1,0,1,0,1],
                        'x':[1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.]})
t1.set_index(['i1','i2'], inplace=True)
t1.sort_index(inplace=True)
t2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'i1':[0,0,1,1,2,2],
                        'i2':[2,3,2,3,2,3],
                        'x':[7.,8.,9.,10.,11.,12.]})
t2.set_index(['i1','i2'], inplace=True)
t2.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

```
>>> print(t1)
         x
i1 i2     
0  0   1.0
   1   2.0
1  0   3.0
   1   4.0
2  0   5.0
   1   6.0

>>> print(t2)
          x
i1 i2      
0  2    7.0
   3    8.0
1  2    9.0
   3   10.0
2  2   11.0
   3   12.0
```

Expected result:

```
          x
i1 i2      
0  0    1.0
   1    2.0
   2    7.0
   3    8.0
1  0    3.0
   1    4.0
   2    9.0
   3   10.0
2  0    5.0
   1    6.0
   2   11.0
   3   12.0
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think there won't be an already implemented answer for your specific use case. If the second frame contains always larger elements than the first frame for the second index level, one could think of "grouping" by first level and contacting the frames on the level below. However, since the list sizes might differ and we might not have clear separation of values on the second index level, the sorting algorithms always will do a full sort here. They won't use the information that the concatenated second level consists of two ordered list.

Comment: There is no assumption about index values: the only assumption which can be made (if it helps) is that the two indices have no intersection.

Comment: This implies, that you have to implement the merge-step or merge sort on the second key level. This is, right now, not implemented in pandas. Hence, you would need to split you index in the first level (btw. this would be nice for distributed computing) and then you would need to apply the merge step on your own. However, as @coldspeed mentioned in one of the answers, the theoretical performance gain might get lost due to overhead in a new implementation and a quick sort might be faster. May I ask, why you would need this kind of complexity?

Comment: I need it to efficiently process very large data sets, which do not fit into memory even on a server with hundreds of GB of RAM. I want to split the data into smaller pieces and when I make a selection from the pieces, I want to merge them algorithmically efficiently into a DataFrame which fits into RAM and will be actually processed. I experimented with distributed computing of the data, but so far I am not very happy with the results.

Comment: I don't think pandas is in that case the right tool. Did you checkout dask?  What about spark/pyskark? Why were you not satisfied, too slow?

Comment: I am experimenting with dask right now, but it seems I need more time to figure how to use it efficiently. Their documentation is somewhat disorganized to my taste: instead of giving a coherent story explaining how to use the tool well with simple examples, explaining all the terms before they are used, one has to jump around and some critical pieces of information, which have to be in the 1st paragraph of introduction, are scattered around and are often somewhere in the end.

Comment: don't forget: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a candidate answer. I am still working to confirm its algorithmic efficiency. Please, comment if you have an opinion:

```py
def linConcat(t1, t2):
    t = t1.reindex( index=t1.index.union(t2.index) )
    t.loc[t2.index,:] = t2
    return t
```

```
>>> linConcat(t1, t2)
          x
i1 i2      
0  0    1.0
   1    2.0
   2    7.0
   3    8.0
1  0    3.0
   1    4.0
   2    9.0
   3   10.0
2  0    5.0
   1    6.0
   2   11.0
   3   12.0
```

Comment: Have you tried timing this function on a larger data set? I have benchmarked it against t1.append(t2).sort_index() on the data you have posted and get the same performance.

Comment: I did test it on a few GB of data. It seems that even though 'linConcat' is likely to be O(N), it is still much slower (probably, due to Python implementation of reindex or union or loc) than t1.append(t2).sort_index(): ~13 times slower, to be exact, in my test. A better implementation of merging sorted DataFrames is needed. In any case, both versions are too slow for me.